# Making BBcode parser with PEG problem

Tags: ruby, parsing, bbcode, treetop, peg

I am making bbcode parser with PEG (Citrus implementation for Ruby) and I am stuck on parsing this `[b]sometext[anothertext[/b]`

There is code

```
grammar BBCodeParser
  rule document
    (open_tag | close_tag | new_line | text)*
  end
  rule open_tag
    ("[" tag_name "="? tag_data? "]")
  end

  rule close_tag
    ("[/" tag_name "]") 
  end

  rule text
    [^\n\[\]]+
  end

  rule new_line
    ("\r\n" | "\n")
  end

  rule tag_name
    # [p|br|b|i|u|hr|code|quote|list|url|img|\*|color]
    [a-zA-Z\*]+
  end

  rule tag_data
    ([^\[\]\n])+
  end
end
```

Problem is with rule `text` I dont know how to say, that text can contain everything except \r, \n, open_tag or close_tag.
With this implementation it fail on example because of exclude of [ and ] (thats wrong)

So finaly question is how to do rule, that can match anything except \r, \n or exact match of open_tag or close_tag

If you have solution for another PEG implementation, give it there too. I can switch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered a similar problem just a while ago. There is a trick to do this:
You need to say match `open_tag`, followed by everything that is not a closing tag and then `closing_tag`. So this gives the following rule

```
rule tag
  open_tag ((!open_tag | !close_tag | !new_line ) .)+ close_tag
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This would parse any text and continue recursively when the `[` wasn't the beginning of another tag.

```
rule text
    [^\n\[\]]+ (!open_tag text)?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
rule text
    [^\n\[\]]+ (!open_tag text)?
end
```

ends up with Parse Error

I tried to continue with this idea and result was `([^\n] (!open_tag | !close_tag) text*)`
But it will fail too. It will match `"sometext[anothertext[/b]"`

Find temp solution
`((!open_tag | !close_tag | !new_line) .)`
It will find just one letter by one letter, but ignore all open and close tags. These letters i can join together later :)